# Django ordering parent model by count of children models in (one to many relation)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose we haw django models `Parent`, and `Child`. `Child` belongs to one `Parent` and one `Parent` can have multiple children.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   pass

class Child(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

I would like to obtain set of all parents ordered by the number of children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`child_set` is the default `related_name` of your `parent` field in the `Child` model. If you've specified a different one, you will have to change the code accordingly.

```
from django.db.models import Count

ordered_parents = Parent.objects.annotate(num_children=Count('child_set')).order_by('-num_childen')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this answer using the search terms: “django order by set size”, hope those tags will help people in the future :)

Comment: How to pass condition to Count()? I mean count with children field condition check.

Answer (score 1):

read up on [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) functions in django docs 
and in any case, you can do parent_instance.child_set.count() to get the number of children
and if i'm not mistaken you can filter and also order_by that relation.
here's a link for [reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)